# Question regarding Form, View and dynamic queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hey guys I have a question regarding form and queryset:

1. Im creating a form where I select a faction from a list of factions.
2. After the form is created, im redirect to another form where I can add soldiers  to this list, but I see every soldiers of every factions in this form, I would like to be able to see ONLY soldiers of the faction I selected on the previous form.

Can you help please on this please ? Im a bit lost on what to search for...

My models:

```
class Faction(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     picture = models.FileField(blank=True,)
     race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None, blank=True, null=True)
     def __str__(self):
            return self.title
     def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("home")



class List(models.Model):
    faction = models.ForeignKey(Faction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    format_points = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("home")

class Soldier(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    picture = models.FileField(blank=True,)
    points = models.IntegerField()
    factions = models.ManyToManyField(Faction)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class SoldierToList(models.Model):
    soldier = models.ForeignKey(Soldier, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

My views:

```
class ListCreateFormView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'armybuilder_list_create.html'
    model = List
    form_class = CreateListForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.race = "toto"
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('add_unit_to_list', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

class AddUnitsToListFormView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    model = SoldierToList
    form_class = SoldierToListForm
    template_name = 'armybuilder_add_unit_to_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Soldier.objects.filter(factions=Tyranids) ## for some test, I need to change this line I think ? 
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.list_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My forms:

```
class CreateListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ('faction','title', 'format_points', 'description')

class SoldierToListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SoldierToList
        fields = ('soldier',)
```

My urls:

```
path('list/create', ListCreateFormView.as_view(), name='create_list'),
path('list/own/<int:pk>/addunit', AddUnitsToListFormView.as_view(), name='add_unit_to_list'),
```

Thanks for your help and have a great day !

Answer (score 0):

pass the primary key of the selected Faction to the form and initialise the form.

`def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    factions_obj = Faction.objects.get(pk=faction_pk)
    self.fields['soldier'].queryset = factions_obj.soldier_set.all()`

Comment: Where should I pass rhe pk of the selected Faction to the form ?

Comment: you need to redefine your AddUnitsToListFormView as AddUnitsToListFormView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView), then override get and post method. def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs)  form=SoldierToListForm(faction_pk=kwargs['pk']),

Comment: where do I put the _init__ method , in my form ?